# Zend Form displaying the elements dynamically which have the protected members

Tags: php, zend-framework

have a problem with showing the elements in Zend form.In my form have protected variables are there dynamically i want to hide the some fields which is matches the  "showmod==0" how to do that ?

```
code:Controller:$form = $this->view->formFilter = new Fields_Form_Standard(array( 'item' => Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject(), 'topLevelId' => $topLevelId, 'topLevelValue' => $topLevelValue, ));
View: $form=$this->formFilter; foreach($form->getElements() as $element){ $mod=$element->showmod;}
Result is:
object(Fields_Model_Rowset)#643 (13) {
    ["_data":protected] => array(49) {[0]=>array(17) {
        ["field_id"] => string(1) "1"
        ["showmod"] => string(1) "0" ...etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some more code? Can't make out what your asking.

Comment: not in the comment in your question.

Comment: my requirement is to hide the form attributes which is have the showmod as 0 Mean is there any way to hide the form attributes dynamically ?

Comment: Try $element->toArray(); and than $element['showmod'];

Comment: am able to get showmod but my intention is how to hide form dynamically attribute which is have the showmod=1

Comment: see my answer. Is this you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you can do this.

```
foreach($form->getElements() as $element) {
  if($element->shoeMod == 1){
     echo $element;
   }
}
```

And make sure you don't have any validators on these field.